# Improving loading speed performance of Rails app with Spree engine

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

Hi I have a Ruby on Rails 4 application with a Spree Engine.

The problem is that is it quite slow and every time I reload a page it takes a long time to load (9 seconds in the last attempt)

I saw on the spree github page that the issue is known and there is a solution where they suggest to precompile assets with bundle exec rake assets:precompile:nondigest command.

Unfortunately when I run this command the rake is aborted. I have run the command with trace

bundle exec rake assets:precompile:nondigest --trace
rake aborted!

Don't know how to build task 'assets:precompile:nondigest'
/home/luca/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:49:in `[]'
/home/luca/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:148:in`invoke_task'
/home/luca/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/luca/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in`each'
/home/luca/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/home/luca/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in`run_with_threads'
/home/luca/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/home/luca/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in`block in run'
/home/luca/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/luca/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in`run'
/home/luca/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.1/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/luca/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/rake:23:in`load'
/home/luca/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/rake:23:in `'

I suspect that the solution of precompiling assests was optimised for Ruby on Rails 3 and it's not working with Rails 4.

Can you advise on how to resolve this or if you have alternatives to speed up the loading time?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

The correct command to run is actually the below and it was run without errors

bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development

Speed of loading page seems marginally faster.

WARNING: Using the precompile rake task in development will prevent
any changes to asset files from being automatically loaded in when you
reload the page. You must re-run the precompile task for changes to
become available.**

Rails also provides the following rake task that will delete the entire public/assets directory, this can be helpful to clear out development assets before committing.

rake assets:clean

Comment: `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development` doesn't help for me. :(